# Variable type matching problem with Eigen

Tags: xcode, for-loop, ubuntu, gcc, eigen

I am using Eigen on google cloud platform on an ubuntu machine. I have installed gcc-7 and I am trying to run a C++ code containing a huge matrix (1000X1000) of doubles.
The code is running fine on Xcode 11.3 with clang, but on the ubuntu machine I am having a problem with variable type conversion. 
The part of the code which is causing problems:

```
Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> Mat(double x, double y, double En, int Np, double Kmax){
Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> M(Np, Np);
double eps = (double)Kmax / (double)Np;
double result, error;
struct params ps;
ps.x = x;
ps.y = y;
ps.En = En;
gsl_set_error_handler_off();
gsl_integration_workspace * w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (iters);
gsl_function F;
F.function = &intDeltFunc;
F.params = &ps;
gsl_integration_qags (&F, 0, y, 0, prec, iters, w, &result, &error);
gsl_integration_workspace_free (w);
for ( int i = 0; i < Np  ; i++){
    for ( int j = 0; j < Np ; j++){
        double p = eps * i + y;
        double q = eps * j + y;
        if ( (j == 0) || (j == Np - 1) ){
            M(i , j) =  Diag(p, q, x, y, En) + eps * Integral(p, q, x, y, En, result) / 2.0;
        }
        else{
            M(i , j) = Diag(p, q, x, y, En) + eps * Integral(p, q, x, y, En, result);
        }
    }
}
return M;}
```

Here Np = 1000.

The problem encountered with ubuntu:

[image: Screenshot]

```
main.cpp:247:26: error: no viable overloaded '='
            M(i , j) = DiagTerm + 0.5 * eps * IntegralTerm;
            ~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:139:14: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
      from 'double' to 'const Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>,
      double, double> >' for 1st argument
    Derived& operator=(const MatrixBase& other);
```

I have tried to download Eigen multiple times, to refer the compiler to its exact location when compiling, and also to use clang (which Xcode uses) and I still have the problem.
Do you have any ideas what might be the problem ?

Comment: Are you using the same C++ version with either compiler? Which one?

Comment: "Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)" on the Mac. On Ubuntu "clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)".

Comment: I meant the C++ version like C++98, C++03, C++11, C++14, C++17 or C++20.

Comment: GNU Standard C++ Library v3 on Ubuntu.
On mac c++ 4.2.1

Comment: Again: This is NOT the LANGUAGE STANDARD.  This is only the revision of some support libs. Each compiler has its default, which may change from compiler version to compiler version.  For example, with g++ you can make the standard explicit by means of `g++ -std=c++11`.  If not explicit, it's implicit. I am referring to this standard. Moreover, libraries / code should always mention for which C++ versions they are supposed to work.

Comment: As @emacsdrivesmenuts, says but also, which version of Eigen are you using (on each platform)? And more importantly, please provide a [mre] -- e.g., what are `Diag`, `Integral`, `struct params`? Do you need the gsl code to reproduce the error? If not remove it from the MRE.